# Does MS-Graph have a similar feature like Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js, office-addins

I need to implement a notification like the one provided by the office.js method Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages using MS-Graph (or other backend outlook API).

Does MS-Graph provide this type of notification or any other notification for emails that show on the outlook client when the user opens an email?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. You need to develop an Outlook add-in for displaying notification messages.

Also you may consider using MailTips. MailTips are informative messages displayed to users while they're composing a message. While a new message is open and being composed, Exchange analyzes the message (including recipients). If a potential problem is detected, the user is notified with a MailTip prior to sending the message. Using the information in the MailTip, the user can adjust the message to avoid undesirable situations or non-delivery reports (also known as NDRs or bounce messages). Read more about that in the [MailTips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/mailtips/mailtips) and [Configure custom MailTips for recipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/mailtips/configure-custom-mailtips) articles in MSDN.

See [mailTips resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mailtips?view=graph-rest-1.0) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems MailTips works only during email composition. 

We need something to display notifications/alerts on received messages, similarly to the Organization-wide message disclaimers, but without modifying the email (i.e. notifications can change after further analysis).

Comment: Good ask @oscar, unfortunately i dont remember there is one.